# Hilbert class field of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-39})$

Tags: class-field-theory

Is the Hilbert class field of $K=\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt{-39}\right)$ is equal to   $K\left(\sqrt{-39},\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{13}}}{2}\right)$

Comment: I don't know, is it? What have you tried? What are your ideas? It at least has $\Gal(K(\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{\sqrt{13}+1})/K)=\mathbb{Z}_4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\text{Cl}(K)=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Have you gotten anywhere on the splitting yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Lemmermayer's computation it is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-39},\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{13}})$, see "Class field towers".

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde Thank you very much for the answer and for suggesting a book too..