# primitive element for a Hilbert class field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem which I found in a book.

Find a primitive element for the Hilbert class field for $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$? Any hints..

Comment: Looking at the factorization of just one integer can yield some hints. For example, $18 = (1 - \sqrt{-17})(1 + \sqrt{-17}) = 2 \times 3^2$, meaning the ring of integers is not a UFD so the class number is greater than $1$, and furthermore, one factorization has one prime factor than the other, so the class number is greater than $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Franz Lemmermayer's computation the Hilbert class field of $k=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$ is $k(\sqrt{4+\sqrt{17}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17},\sqrt{4+\sqrt{17}})$, see his book [Class field towers](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/pcft.pdf) for details of this computation. The class group $Cl(k)$ is isomorphic to $C_4$, hence the class number of $k$ is equal to $4$.
For another example see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513129/hilbert-class-field-of-mathbb-q-sqrt-39?rq=1).